# background images with carreirwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm having trouble getting images I'm uploading using carrierwave to show in the blog I'm working on.

Here's the view code:

```
<div class="entry-header">
   <div class="entry-image" style="background: image-url(<%= image_tag @blog.image_url.to_s %>)"> </div>
   <h1 class="entry-title"><%= @blog.title %></h1>
</div>
```

Currently it's displaying `)">` where the image and title should be. I'm able to make that disappear by removing the `=` in the image tag, but that also doesn't solve the problem.

Here's the blog model:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
validates :body, presence: true
mount_uploader :image, BlogImageUploader
end
```

And I haven't made any changes tot he generic carrierwave generated uploader, though I can post that too if it's helpful. Anyone have any ideas?

As requested, the rendered html:

```
<div class="entry-header">
    <div class="entry-image" style="background: <img src=" uploads="" blog="" image="" 980190964="" gcentral.jpg"="" alt="Gcentral">"&gt; </div>
    <h1 class="entry-title">Grand central test</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML output from your page for everything from `<div class="entry-header">...` to the closing `</div>`?

Comment: Just posted it above. I'm not super familiar with what it's supposed to be like here, particularly for background images. It seems to be getting the image name right at least and the blog id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I see what's going on now. When you use `<%= image_tag(...) %>`, Rails generates a `<img src="..." alt="..." foo="..." bar="..." />` tag that is used to display a regular image in a page. What you're going to want is to just output the image URL instead with

```
style="background: url(<%= @blog.image_url %>)"
```

This will print something like `url(http://foo/bar/baz.jpg)` like you want. Note that I also changed `image-url` to `url`, as `image-url` is something that you get to use under the /app/assets/stylesheets files, but isn't available in style attributes. Look up [sprockets](https://github.com/rails/sprockets) for more info if you're curious.

You probably also want to use some sanitization in there, because a crafty hacker could upload an image with a name like `"><script>alert('hacked!')</script>` to execute scripts on your page.

Comment: You nailed in 10 minutes what I've been trying to figure out all day! Thanks! Yeah, I need to go through and do some sanitization for sure. Fortunately, there's a very restrictive permissions system in place that only allows admins to generate new content.