# Rails 4 - dynamic background image

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a rails 4 app, using a dynamic background image.

I've read several posts on SO that say it's best not to defined the object in the css file because it doesnt cache. I've tried to define it in my show page as follows - however nothing renders.

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-lg-4 vc-photo" style= 'background-image: url(<%= image_url @profile.user.avatar.profile.path if @profile.user.avatar? %>);' }>&nbsp;</div>
```

I have also tried (swapping path for url):

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-lg-4 vc-photo" style= 'background-image: url(<%= image_url @profile.user.avatar.profile.url if @profile.user.avatar? %>);' }>&nbsp;</div>
```

When I try inspecting the element in the code inspector, I can see:

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-lg-4 vc-photo" style="background-image: url();" }="">&nbsp;</div>
```

Does anyone see what I've done wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `avatar` has a value? If you change it to `<%= "xxx" if @profile.user.avatar? %>` or something like that do you get the `xxx` in the output?

Comment: (also, you have an extra ` }` which is being translated by the browser into `}=""`, but that's unrelated your problem)

Comment: Hi, the page source shows: <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-4 vc-photo" style= "background-image: url();">&nbsp;</div>

Comment: Oh you saw that comment before I deleted it then... Yeah, I realized the extra `}` was causing the `}=""` so the page source wasn't relevant. Did you try my first suggestion, to see if `avatar` actually has a value?

Answer (score 1):

This should work mate

```
<div id="profile-photo" style="background-image: url(/assets/<%= @user.image.url(:thumb) %>)">
```

Replace the url with your own and do not use image_tag because you only want the url not an image.

Answer (score 0):

`<div class="col-md-5 col-lg-4 vc-photo" style="background-image: url(<%= image_tag @profile.user.avatar.url if @profile.user.avatar.file? %>);">&nbsp;</div>`

Try this if it works.

Edit

`<div class="col-md-5 col-lg-4 vc-photo" style="background-image: url(<%= image_tag @profile.user.avatar.url if @profile.user.avatar? %>);">&nbsp;</div>`

Try it without the file

I found this that should help you:
[background images with carreirwave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33248021/background-images-with-carreirwave)

Comment: Hi, the 'file' bit creates an error message saying no method defined for file. I don't have that defined in my app. The first answer you gave doesnt work either. Thanks anyway

Comment: What kind of gem do you use to do file uploading?

Comment: Check the link cause it is almost the same as yours.

Comment: @HansiCollaku it's not the same - the problem in that post was `image_tag`, not `image_url` - the OP here is using `image_url`